# HTML5 EventSource listener for all events?

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

I have push notifications in my JavaScript client app using EventSource.
I can attach event listeners like this:

```
source.addEventListener('my_custom_event_type', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

But I want to monitor all events that are being pushed from the server (basically for debugging), so if some event is sent but it has no event listener I can easily find it. I mean, I don't want to just "ignore" all events that have no eventListeners binded.

I would expect to do something like this:

```
source.addEventListener('*', function(e) {
  console.debug('Event with no listener attached: ', e);
}, false);
```

But the specification and tutorials like the one at [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) don't specify if this is possible or not.

In the other hand, it may be some firefox/chrome extension that allows to monitor all server events or something. Those things would really help on developing push notifications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

I figure out a solution myself, that also improves tremendously the EventSource interface.

**Server side**: Do not send the event type, just include an additional data field (having that I always use json). So instead of

```
event: eventName
data: {mykey: 'myvalue'}
```

I send this from the server instead:

```
data: {mykey: 'myvalue', eventName: 'eventName'}
```

**Client side**: Now I can use EventSource onmessage callback, that is fired on every message that does not have an event type.

And for bind event listeners, I create a wrapper class with Backbone.Event functionality. The result:

```
// Server Sent Events (Event Source wrapper class)
var MyEventSource = (function() {

  function MyEventSource(url) {
    var self = this;
    _.extend(this, Backbone.Events);

    this.source = new EventSource(url);
    this.source.onmessage = function(event) {
      var data, eventName;
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      var eventName = data.eventName; delete data.eventName;

      // Now we can monitor all server sent events
      console.log('app.server.on ', eventName, '. Data: ', data);

      self.trigger(eventName, data);
    };
  }

  return MyEventSource;
})();
```

Now with this wrapper class, I can easily extend the functionality, all server sent events can be easily monitored and thanks to extending Backbone.Events the event handling in this class is much more powerful.

Usage example:

```
var source = new MyEventSource('url/of/source');

// Add event listener
source.on('eventName', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

// Fire a event (also very useful for testing and debugging!!)
source.trigger('eventName', { mykey: 'myvalue' });

// Unbind event listener (very important for complex applications)
source.off('eventName');
```

Now I have a component that is easy to handle, extend, debug and test.

Comment: "Onmessage callback is fired on every message that **does not have an event type**".  That was seriously useful information to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Just an fyi: calling `onmessage = some_function;` is exactly the same as calling `addEventListener("message", some_function);`. This makes it obvious that messages without an event type are the same as messages with an event type of "message".

Comment: Hello tothemario. For some reason, JSON.parse(event.data) doesn't work for me. Would you be so kind as to provide your server-side way to generate data: {mykey: 'myvalue', eventName: 'eventName'} ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tothemario`! thanks for the answer, based on your guidance I tried `source.addEventListener('eventName', MyHander, false);` this works without the wrapper. (see my answer below for a full example)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an EventSource, but I was looking for the same thing (a way to catch all incoming events without knowing their type). Without any control over the server sending these events, I ended up just writing it with an XHR, in case anyone else comes across this:

```
function eventStream(path, callback){
    //Create XHR object
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //initialize storage for previously fetched information
    var fetched='';

    //Set readystatechange handler
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){

        //If the connection has been made and we have 200, process the data
        if(xhr.readyState>2 && xhr.status==200){
            //save the current response text
            var newFetched=xhr.responseText;

            //this is a stream, so responseText always contains everything
            //from the start of the stream, we only want the latest
            var lastFetch=xhr.responseText.replace(fetched, '');

            //Set the complete response text to be removed next time 
            var fetched=newFetched;

            //callback to allow parsing of the fetched data
            callback(lastFetch);
        }
    };

    //open and send to begin the stream;
    xhr.open('GET', path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

parseEvents=function(response){
    var events=[];
    //split out by line break
    var lines=response.split("\n");

    //loop through the lines
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){

        //each event consists of 2 lines, one begins with
        //"name:", the other with "data"
        //if we hit data, process it and the previous line
        if(lines[i].substr(0, lines[i].indexOf(':'))=='data'){

            //add this event to our list for return
            events.push({

               //get the event name
               name: lines[i-1].split(':')[1].trim(),
               //parse the event data
               data: $.parseJSON(lines[i].substr(lines[i].indexOf(':')+1).trim())
            });
        }
    }
    //return the parsed events
    return events;
};

evenStream('http://example.com/myEventPath', function(response){
    var events=parseEvents(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Trey for posting your code, it was extremely useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script>
    var content = '';
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
    {
      var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
      source.onmessage = function(event)
      {
        content+=event.data + "<br>";
        $("#result").html(content);
      };
    }
    else
    {
      $("#result").html("Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...");
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: This will not work since `onmessage` handles only events without the type https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventSource

Answer (score 0):

Credit to user `tothemario` above for the clue I needed to figure this out.

It appears that you CAN send events back to the browser with a custom type, but in order to trigger the MESSAGE event you must assign a listener to the new type rather than the `message` type.

If you look at the client side code below it will hopefully illustrate.

For context, my server sends an event with the custom type `CustomType`. Therefore I subscribe with an event listener to that type, and I add another listener for `message` as a catch all for everything else.

In this workflow, an event that comes to the browser with the `CustomType` a different listener fires.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var CustomTypeList = [];

    function EventSystemOpen(e) {
        console.log("EventSystemOpen", e);
    }

    function EventSystemError(e) {
        console.log("EventSystemOpen", e);
        if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            //
        }
    }

    function GotServerEventMessage(e) {
        console.log("GotServerEventMessage", e);
    }

    function GotCustomType(e) {
        CustomTypeList.push(JSON.parse(e.data));
        console.log("Added CustomType", e, JSON.parse(e.data), CustomTypeList);
    }

    if (!!window.EventSource) {
        var source = new EventSource('api/listen');
        source.addEventListener('open', EventSystemOpen, false);
        source.addEventListener('error', EventSystemError, false);
        source.addEventListener('message', GotServerEventMessage, false);
        source.addEventListener('CustomType', GotCustomType, false);
    }
 </script>
```