# Is it recomended to use Server Sent Events for pushing notifications by continuous querying of the database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, push-notification, server-sent-events

I want to push realtime notifications(DTO Object for the logged-in user) to the client-side by continuously querying the database. I am using Server Side Events to achieve the same. However, I am facing few issues in achieving that. I am using EventSource API in javascript.

1. **POLLING INSIDE AN INFINITE LOOP**

Since my data lies in the database, I constantly need to run queries to fetch the latest entries and use `executor.execute(()->{ while(true) {emitter.send(data)} } Thread.sleep(5000))` until the user logs out. (a)Querying Database in an infinite loop and (b) Creating new ExecutorService objects is causing JDBC pool exhaustion exception and ultimately freezing the application.

2. **USING SPRING BOOT @Scheduled**
   This doesn't work either as I need logged in user_id which I can't get inside @Scheduled annotated method using `SpringContextHolder.getAuthentication` as this Cron is not initiated by the user.

Am I doing wrong here by choosing SSE instead of Web Sockets or is there any way around to implement Server Side for this particular use case?

***Please help/guide me.***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push event to your client, you better have the event concept on your backend as well rather than polling. If you want to poll your database, you better let the client do it. SSE or websocket does not matter in that decision.

CDI events may be a suitable solution for your need.

- Create an `EntityForLoggedInUsersChanged` event class.
- Inject an `Event<EntityForLoggedInUsersChanged>` in your service that alter entities related to loggedin users. fire the event when they do so.
- Create a service that will `@Observe` those events, construct the dto that you want to push, obtain the channel to the relevant users, and push it.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, yes, this is a valid pattern.

Polling every 5 seconds might use less overall resources, than having the database send push notifications (even assuming the DB supports that).

And compared to having the client make, say an AJAX call, every 5 seconds, which requires setting up a DB connection each time, it might also be more efficient (at the expense of keeping the SSE socket open all the time).

> Creating new ExecutorService objects is causing JDBC pool exhaustion exception and ultimately freezing the application.

Is the pool exhaustion coming from having just one user, polling every 5 seconds? Or does it come from having lots of users, each keeping a database connection open?

If the latter, make the pool big enough to support the maximum number of simultaneously connected users you want to allow.

If the former, you either have to release the resource after polling, before doing the 5000ms sleep, or open the resource once, outside the loop, and then find a way to just re-run the query inside the infinite loop.

(Sorry I'm not familiar with `ExecutorService` or `Spring`; it may be that it is just a too high-level abstraction around querying a database, and you need to use lower-level functions?)

By the way, SSE vs. Web Sockets wouldn't make a difference here. Web Sockets give you a more complicated protocol in exchange for it being a two-way connection instead of one-way, but everything else is fairly much the same. I.e. you still have a dedicated socket between client and your web service, and you still have an infinite loop polling the database.

Comment: Just to contradict one of the point above, In case of websocket, I dont need to continuosly loop over my database. Whenever an event happens (lets say creation of a comment/notification), in my application code I can broadcast a message over the dedicated websocket channel.
EventSource does not have the concept of channels.

Comment: @VipulKumar If you can get notified when an event happens in a websocket server (and then broadcast) then you can do it for EventSource too.    (BTW, you can specify `event` header to get the concept of channels, but I generally recommend not using it, and handling everything in a single message handler. E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936764/841830 where the person came to the same conclusion.)

Comment: Darren Cook Thanks for your inputs. However we will still have to loop/poll our database continuously.